# Pass nested hash to subroutine

Tags: perl, hash

I have a multidimensional hash that looks like the following:

```
my %hashTable;
$hashTable{'1'}{'A'} = "red";
$hashTable{'1'}{'B'} = "blue";
$hashTable{'2'}{'A'} = "orange";
$hashTable{'2'}{'B'} = "purple";
```

I want to pass an inner hash as an argument to a subroutine. 
For instance,

```
hashFunc($hashTable{'2'});

sub hashFunc{
     my %innerHash = $_[0];
}
```

However, when I call the function as `hashFunc($hashTable{'2'})`, I receive the error

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected
```

How do I properly provide an inner hash as an argument to a subroutine?

Comment: what version of perl do you use. I did not get any errors with this code.

Comment: I dont get this error as well. Please elaborate on your environment.

Comment: It is absolutely an error in every version of perl. Turn on warnings if you don't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-dimensional data structures are assembled via reference.

`$hashtable{'2'}` is a scalar value, that's reference to a hash.

To use it in a subroutine, you need to dereference it - either *before* sending it:

```
hashFunc( %{$hashtable{'2'}});
```

Which will send a list of values (that you can then assign into a hash as you do).

Or *within* the hash:

```
 my %innerHash = %{$_[0]};
```

However as Borodin points out - this will cause your data structure to be copied, and this is inefficient and rarely necessary.

So you could instead:

```
 my ( $innerHash ) = @_;
```

And then you can access `$innerHash` via dereference operators, like:

```
 print $innerHash -> {'A'};
 foreach my $key ( keys %$innerHash ) { 
    print $key,"\n";
 }
```

etc.

Comment: ***Absolutely not!*** It's misleading to suggest either of those solutions. Dereferencing a hash is only very rarely necessary, and it's far from obvious that the result is a one-level copy of the original which will duplicate data unnecessarily. The reference should be passed directly to the subroutine

Answer (score 4):

Perl hash values must be scalars, and nested data structures are built by using *references* to hashes or arrays for each array or hash value

You need to assign a scalar value within your subroutine, like this

```
hashFunc($hashTable{'2'});

sub hashFunc{
    my ($innerHash) = @_;
    # same as my $innerHash = $_[0]
    ...
}
```

You don't say anything about what you want to do with the secondary hash, but in general you can access an element of the inner hash using `$innerHash->{key}`, or you can use the `keys`, `values`, or `each` operators by dereferencing the value; for instance `for my $k ( keys %$innerHash ) { ... }`

You should take a look at [*Perl references short introduction*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [*Perl data structures intro*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for more information

Answer (score 2):

You need to dereference the inner hash if you need to use it as a hash.

You can do that in the subroutine

```
hashFunc($hashTable{2});
sub hashFunc {
    my %innerHash = %{ $_[0] };
```

or in the calling code

```
hashFunc(%{ $hashTable{2} });
sub hashFunc {
    my %innerHash = @_;
```

But, you usually don't need to use a hash, you can just use the hash reference directly.

```
hashFunc($hashTable{2});
sub hashFunc {
    my $innerHashRef = shift;
    # Whatever you need to do with the hash:
    $innerHashRef->{key}{A} = ... 
    for my $key (keys %$innerHashRef) {
    ...
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't need to do `my %innerHash = @_;` in the second case?

Comment: This has the same problem as [Sobrique's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38247206/622310). Dereferencing an entire hash is wasteful and almost certainly unnecessary